# How to improve Webview performence in Android?

Tags: android

I am developing an app in android using WebView.  My HTML page is
coming from the GAE server.  The page contains a lot oh high resolution
images, is there a way to store and reference those images from the
assets folder, or reference local images.  That will help me increase
the performance.  I would want to keep the HTML on the server and not
make it local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you cannot store images in the assets folder programatically.
Second, the problem is with your images. If you're developing for a smartphone, it would make no sense to use high-res images with the app. If you have control over your server, do that. Otherwise, there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you put your image in drawable?

If you put your image in assets, then you can load it by the code:

```
String str = "\assets\resName";
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(str);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```